# Using Cloud Formation can i migrate existing VPC from one amazon account to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration, amazon-vpc, aws-cli

I want to migrate existing VPC, subnets, routetables etc from current amazon account to another amazon account using cloud formation.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a CloudFormation template for your existing VPC resources, create one.

Then re-create the VPC on the other AWS account by creating a CloudFormation stack with that template.

You might find CloudFormer useful when creating the template based on your current VPC: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html

Comment: Other similar services... [Hava](http://hava.io), [Visualops](http://visualops.io).